# OpenSSH permissions, and locked out questions

Tags: ssh, permissions

When attempting to SSH from my laptop to an EC2 instance in Amazon, the ssh command failed telling me the permissions to my .pem file were too open. I used chmod to set the permissions on the file to rwx------ and the directory to the same.   It is still giving me the same error:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions for 'myKeyPair.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "XXXxxxXXXxxx.pem": bad permissions
```

It's not unprotected.  How can this be?

Secondly I once wasn't allowed to connect (there was no error to tell me this) but it was because there were too many failed attempts, and ssh had locked up.  There was an option to clear the lock that I don't see on the OpenSSH man page.  Can someone tell me that option?

Unrelated side note: I may have to use a different ssh client.

Answer (score 0):

You have to shut off the .ssh directory with a 700

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

then give private key  permission 600 as per

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/myKeyPair.pem
```

details see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Comment: You can still use symbolic permissions; just use the right ones - `u=rw`

Comment: The home directory also has to permissions no looser than `0755` if `StrictModes` is enabled.

Comment: Thanks again guys.  I actually had the correct permissions.  I am a *NIX guy, have always been a NIX guy, so I wasn't surprised when it turned out to be Windoze implementation of SSH.   As soon as I used GitBash it worked first try.  Part of the question is still unanswered, about the ssh option to clear the cache after ssh has locked ssh from too many failed attempts.  I know there is an option cause this fixed my ssh issues once.  I don't need it this time but would like to know.

Comment: Sorry if i asked this in the wrong forum, but openSSH is really not a Windows thing, it's an add on, like TCP/IP was an add-on to Windows that came out in 1995 and ran in userland.  TCP/IP came out in UNIX in 1969 and always ran in the kernel space.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH requires `-rw-------` permissions for the private key.

Since you do not have local access, you will have to contact support.

Comment: Thanks Guys!  This leads to the next question.  Both the chmod in PowerShell, run as Administrator,  and my MS Windows WSL Debian shell chmod aren't capable of changing Windows filesystem permissions.  Same thing with GitBash.  workaround?  In Windoze there is a graphical filesystem Permissions GUI tool, but the only users are my account, SYSTEM, and Administrators ( I am one).  Presumably the system needs access to these files for ssh to run?

Comment: If you have a 2nd question, [Ask] a second question. Since your 2nd question is about Windows, ask it elsewhere.